# How to automatically set correct nameserver ip in /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, dns, networkmanager

Edited as per [Bodo's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/330217/bodo) recommendations.

I have the following setup in my home. Optic cable -> ONT + WiFi ( single device: Huawei HG8143A5 ) -> gigabit router ( dlink dir842 connected to ONT through UTP cable ). The ONT has PPPoE connection and the router has Dynamic IP (DHCP) connection set.

Upon connecting to the gigabit router, NetworkManager sets `nameserver 192.168.0.1` in `resolv.conf`. `192.168.0.1` is the default gateway of my computer, but since the router is connected to the ONT, I need to manually change `resolv.conf` to the gateway of the router (the IP of the ONT), not the one of my computer, otherwise I'm getting `Temporary failure in name resolution`. DLink router sets it's `gateway to 192.168.100.1` ( ONT's IP ) and `Primary DNS Server to 192.168.100.1`

How can I pull the gateway of the router automatically into resolv.conf?
How would I tackle this if I didn't have access to the router's interface to find out it's gateway? My android devices seem to find a way, although they display `Connected, no internet` for a while, until they figure it out.

If anyone feels generous I would also like to understand why/how this is happening.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Does "ONT + WiFi device" mean a single device or two separate devices? Is your router connected via Ethernet or WiFi? How is your Android device connected? What type of router do you have? If it has different operating modes, which mode do you use? Normally I would expect that the router automatically advertises a working DNS server, either by telling the address of an upstream server or by implementing a forwarding server on the router itself.

Comment: I have updated per your suggestions. I hate that this ONT doesn't let me use it as a bridge and make the PPPoE connection from the router directly. When I had two DLink routers in series (one set as PPPoE and the other as Dynamic IP) I didn't encounter this problem. I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a CentOS/Fedora/Red Hat based distro, edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-XXXX. If you are using SUSE/OpenSUSE, edit /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-XXXX

Add the following, replace with the DNS servers and domain you need:

```
PEERDNS=no
DNS1=1.0.0.1
DNS2=8.8.8.8
DOMAIN=something.org
```

Then just restart the interface.

Or use nm-connection-editor and set the following, which does exactly the same thing.

[image: Network Manager Conection Editor]

Comment: I'm on arch, kernel 5.9.4, can't find that file. How can I find out the DNS and domain that I need?

Comment: Use the same domain of your local network or anything you want. That's just used to complete queries when you use short names for DNS queries (ex: doing a query for 'server1' becomes 'server1.somedomain.com'). Your ISP should provide you with the DNS servers you need.

You may use any of the public DNS servers (google it, list is big). Suggestions:

    Cisco OpenDNS: 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220;
    Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1;
    Google Public DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4;
    Quad9: 9.9.9.9 and 149.112.112.112.